# Extracting the text from connector start and end point in Visio C#

Tags: c#, com, interop, visio, flowchart

How can we extract the start and end point details of a connector between two shapes in a visio.

```
using Visio = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio

class Program
{
   Application visApp = new Application();
   Document visDoc = visApp.Documents.Open(filePath);

   // Get the first page in the sample drawing.
     page = visDoc.Pages[1];

    // Look at each shape in the collection.
            foreach (Shape shape in page.shapes)
            { 
                if (shp.OneD == -1)
                {
                  //Need clues- How to proceed ?
                }

            }
}
```

In the below image, I would want to extract 'XYZ' and 'PQR'.

[image]

Comment: Do you know where the connector shape comes from - ie which stencil and which master name?

Comment: @JohnGoldsmith - No, I need to get the to and from details from a connector also.

Comment: Unless this is a builtin shape that you can predict the structure then you’ll need to discover this yourself by looking at the shape. I would guess that this is a group shape containing one or more sub-shapes to hold the text. It might also be that the top level shape contains one text item and the other is in a single sub-shape. Assuming this is based on a master, once you know the structure it should be simpler to get hold of the text. i would start by looking at the shape using the Drawing Explorer in Visio.